# how export to pdf with embeded fonts in centos soffice command line?

Tags: pdf, libreoffice, soffice

If I save DOCX file with embeded fonts option in MS Word, i can open it in libreoffice writer gui in linux, and see it with the original fonts that are not installed on Linux.

i can also export it to PDF from libreoffice writer menu button and fonts embeded in the file and it will look good on any computer.

But when I try to convert it to PDF using a command line in centos such "unoconv" or "soffice" or "libreoffice", the output not include the fonts that are embedded, and it only with defualt fonts.

Is there a parameter that i can add the command to come out the same as i press the button on the libreoffice writer gui?
Or does anyone have another solution to export to PDF and make it look the same with those fonts?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found a good solution,
But for now I've added a lot of fonts to my server, and thus the file therefore included fonts.